# Loop through each pixel of a raster stack and return a time series of pixels using Python

Tags: python, numpy, raster, rasterio

I'm new to Python language and I'm trying to loop through a rasterstack and store pixels in a time-series manner.

For example, suppose I have three rasters of three dates, for 2020, 2021, 2022:

```
 A = array([[[0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5,
              0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]],
            [[1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3,
              1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7]],
            [[1.8, 1.9, 2.0, 2.1,
              2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5]]])
```

I would like to create a new array with arrays whose elements are displayed like:

```
  B = array([[0.2, 1.0, 1.8],
            [0.3, 1.1, 1.9],
            [0.4, 1.2, 2.0],
            ...
            [0.9, 1.7, 2.5]])
```

i.e.,  `[0.2, 1.0, 1.8]` is formed by the first element (0.2) which was the first element of first array of `A`,
the second element (1.0) is the first element of second array of `A`,
the third element (1.8) is the first element of third array of `A`.
Then for the next array `[0.3, 1.1, 1.9]`, the first element (0.3) is the second element of first array of `A`. The second element (1.1) is the second element of second array of `A` and so on.

Is there any easy way to do this without a lot of loops?
To get some data:

```
    data = np.random.random((3, 4, 4)) 
    stack = np.dstack(data) #just to change to (4,4,3), number of images for last
```

Comment: Can you correct you rexample array to something proper, you're missing commas and parentheses as well as mixing up `[]` and `()` from what it seems like.
Also what is your actual goal? Because the data seems to be in the format you want to me.
Do you just want to add column & row names?
What is your reproducible example demonstraiting, it seems unrelated to the rest of the question.

Comment: Thank you! I edited the question and I think it is correct now with `()` and `[]` and clearer. The reproducible example is just to get some data to put in the format I would like. If I have in `stack`  `[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [7.0, 8.0, 9.0], [11.0, 12.0, 15.0]]` then I would like the output as `[[1.0, 7.0, 11.0], [2.0, 8.0, 12.0], [3.0, 9.0, 15.0]]`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transpose the original array with the code below, I resize after the transpose to get rid of the extra dimension but depending on your actual data you might not need/want it.

```py
arr = np.array([
    [[0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]],
    [[1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7]],
    [[1.8, 1.9, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5]],
])
tr = arr.transpose()
#tr = array([
#    [[0.2, 1. , 1.8]],
#    [[0.3, 1.1, 1.9]],
#    [[0.4, 1.2, 2. ]],
#    [[0.5, 1.3, 2.1]],
#    [[0.6, 1.4, 2.2]],
#    [[0.7, 1.5, 2.3]],
#    [[0.8, 1.6, 2.4]],
#    [[0.9, 1.7, 2.5]],
#])
reshaped = tr.reshape((8,3))
#reshaped = array([
#    [0.2, 1. , 1.8],
#    [0.3, 1.1, 1.9],
#    [0.4, 1.2, 2. ],
#    [0.5, 1.3, 2.1],
#    [0.6, 1.4, 2.2],
#    [0.7, 1.5, 2.3],
#    [0.8, 1.6, 2.4],
#    [0.9, 1.7, 2.5],
#])
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about transpose working in multi-arrays like that, also thanks for the reshape tip!